# Many-to-one searches in Hibernate with Criterias

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a two model, Club and Location. A club can only have one location, and a location can have many clubs. In my pojo classes, I define these two like below:

```
// Club.java
public class Club {
    private Location location;
    // some other attributes and getters/setters
}

// Location.java
public class Location {
    private int id; // primary key
    // some attribues and getters/setters
}
```

And my hibernate mappings are:

```
// some other mappings, foreign key is "location" column in my actual table, as // can be seen below
<many-to-one name="location" column="location" class="path/to/Club.java">
```

***I need to search Clubs by their Location***. And I make use of criterias as below,

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Club.class);
crit.createAlias("location.id", "location");
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("location", locationId);
```

However, I get the error
**hibernate.QueryException: not an association: id**

Whenever I  try replacing "location.id" with "location", then I get an **IllegalArgumentException occured while calling getter Location.id** error. So far, I could not achieve my goal with both ways. Been searcing it on web for days, but none of them was useful. What is the problem here?

Comment: have you tried `private Integer id` ? should not use primitives with hibernate...

Comment: @joc will do, regardless of the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criteria.createAlias is for association not for entity properties. See java documents.

For your requirement it should be like

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Club.class);
crit.createAlias("location", "location");
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("location.id", locationId);
```

I haven't tested the code. Let's know how it goes.